# Android: Spinner list text in white color

Tags: android, list, background, spinner, background-color

In below case how to change adapter list background color.

```
 MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, "Your List",null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is solution for changing color.

**Use code :**

```
MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(Activity.this, 
       android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, "Your List",null);
```

**instead of:**

```
MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this,
       android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, "Your List",null);
```